# curl retrieves old version of page

Tags: c++, curl

I am using curl to get a HTML file on my bitbucket repository. I cant give you the direct link as the repo is private, but its from the following form: https://bitbucket.org/uname/project/downloads/index.html

I do this using the following code:

```
mCurl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_URL, String::toAnsi(address).c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, _internal_curl_write_callback);
curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, this);
curl_easy_perform(mCurl);
```

While at first the results seemed ok after ive changed the page (deleted it on the repo and uploaded it new) curl still retrieves the old version of the page even if i restart the application. In the browser however if I enter that link I get the new one.

Is there caching in curl that I can disable? Or do you know of any other possible explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Try `curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1L);`

Comment: I tried this, but sadly it didnt change the behavior. I should have probably said that this persists even if i restart my application (edited into the topic now)

Comment: Wierd guess: 1) try set `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`  as your browser. 2) try move the executable to another directory.

Comment: you could append a parameter to get a "new" resource, like `https://bitbucket.org/uname/project/downloads/index.html?nochache=timestamp` (to preclude cache issues) and make sure the file get overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

To request a non-cached page from the server, set the header option `Cache-control: no-cache`.  You can do this as follows with cURL:

```
struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Cache-control: no-cache");
curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
```

If you're reusing connections in the same program, you may also want to enable:

```
curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE , true);
```

Comment: Sadly i couldnt make it work, even with must-revalidate and other options about cache control. It always is 20 minutes of delay for CURL while the browser (mine and also other peoples) gets the new version. Probably its a problem of bitbucket.

Comment: There's definitely no problem here that can't be overcome.  There isn't anything magically different between cURL and your browser.  If you suspect bitbucket is doing filtering by user agent, just change cURL's user agent to be identical to that of your browser.

Comment: I tried that as well (`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36`) and yet still the same result. However once in a dozen times also the browser downloaded an old version. But that was a one timer, for cURL its every time.

Comment: Are you behind a transparent caching proxy of some kind, such as Squid?  This discussion is really getting a bit beyond the scope of the original question, since it sounds like something is misbehaving and it may be bitbucket itself, but I just want to emphasise that logically there can be no difference in behaviour assuming the input you send to the server is identical, and curl has the ability to duplicate any data you can send with your browser.  Have you considered grabbing a packet capture of the exchange between your browser and bitbucket, and comparing that to that of your curl app?